# Jquery .sort 2d object affects earlier variables (console.log before the sort returns also the sorted object)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an 2d object by a value inside the 2nd object. But when i do that the console.log before the sorting returns the exact same (already sorted) value as after the sorting.

Here is my example code

```
var result = {
"success": true,
"instances": [
  {
    "InstanceId": "428",
    "content": "1234"
  },
  {
    "InstanceId": "429",
    "content": "4321"
  },
  {
    "InstanceId": "427",
    "content": "im a rebel"
  }
]
}

var old = result.instances;
var newww = result.instances;
console.log(old, 'old');
newww.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a['InstanceId'] - b['InstanceId'];
});
console.log(newww, 'new');
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/cgovohgL/

Thanks for your time

**Added info:**
console.dir gives the same result

Comment: Console.dir gives the same result

Comment: Yeah.. I guess cloning is the only way. Have a look at the other answers.